# Construct First 3 Orthogonal Polynomials with Gram-Schmidt

Tags: polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials, gram-schmidt, laguerre-polynomials

Consider the set of functions $u(x)=x^n,\,\,$ with $n=0,1,2, \dots$.

**Use the Gram-Schmidt procedure to construct the first 3 orthogonal polynomials** of:

$$\text{Laguerre:} \;\;\;\;L_n(x),\;\;\;\; \text{Range:}\;\; 0 \le x < \infty, \;\;\;\;      \text{Weight:}\;\; w(x)=e^{-x}.$$

For these polynomials the normalization is

$$\int_0^\infty [L_n(x)]^2 e^{-x} dx \,=\, 1.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the first 3 orthogonal polynomials we are looking for $v_0(x), v_1(x), v_2(x)$. We are going to solve for $v_0(x)$ by starting with $u_0(x) = 1$ as your first polynomial. You can find the normalization constant $N$ by solving:

### $\int^\infty_0 v_0(x)^2 e^{-x}dx = \frac{1}{N^2} $

Your normalized polynomial $v_0(x)$ will be $Nu_0(x)$. In this case, you will find that N=1, or that your function  $v_0(x) = 1$ is already normalized.

Then continue with $u_1(x) = x$. You have to make it orthogonal with your first orthogonal polynomial $v_0(x)$ by evaluating the integral:

### $\int^\infty_0 u_1(x)v_0(x) e^{-x}dx$

You have to subtract the result of this integral from $u_1(x)$ to get your first orthogonal polynomial. The integral turns out to be -1 (solved by integration by parts), and so you get $v_1 = x - 1$. You can find that the normalization constant is 1 by doing the integration

### $\int^\infty_0 v_1(x)^2 e^{-x}dx = \frac{1}{N^2} $

Finally,to find $v_2(x)$, we start with $u_2(x) = x^2$ and make it orthogonal to both of our polynomials $v_0(x)$ and $v_1(x)$. This time we have to subtract the following two integrals from $u_2(x)$:

### $\int^\infty_0 u_2(x)v_0(x) e^{-x}dx$

### $\int^\infty_0 u_2(x)v_1(x) e^{-x}dx$.

This should lead to $v_2(x) = x^2 - 4x + 2$. Do the usual normalization integral, and this time you will find that $N=\frac{1}{2}$.

You can check your answers here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#The_first_few_polynomials
(Note that our $v_1(x)$ has a minus sign as compared to theirs. That is fine, since a minus sign doesn't change the fact the orthnormality of the polynomial)